# multiplying the first number of its row by the number at the top of its column

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```
def multiplication_table(start, stop):
    for x in (start,start+1,stop):
        for y in (start,start+1,stop):
            print(str(x*y), end=" ")
        print()

multiplication_table(1, 3)
```

The output is

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

How does the for loops works? Although I got the answer right, I don't understand how the for loops works in this way

Comment: Your double for loop will make every number multiply with every number so you have 3^2 results.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I'm over or under simplifying it. When the function (multiplication_table) is called, you pass in start=1 and stop=3.

The first/outer FOR loop (for x in...) begins first. It will loop 3 times - for x=start, x = start+1 and x=stop. Using your input, this means it will be processed for x=1,2 and 3.

Because the FOR clauses are nested, each loop of the first/outer FOR loop executes the whole inner FOR process - the only difference being the value for x, each time. The 3 integers in the first row are the 3 results of the 3 second/inner FOR loop for x=1. The 3 integers in the second row are the 3 results of the second/inner FOR loop for x=2. The 3 integers in the third row are the 3 results of the second/inner FOR loop for x=3. All in all, the inner loop is executed 9 times (providing the 9 integer results).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the loop that is executing based on the input arguments to your function,

```
for x in (1, 2, 3):
  for y in (1, 2, 3):
    print(str(x*y), end=" ")
print()
```

For visualizing and to better understand your code try http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and see what happens at each execution/step.